# Prove $\inf\{x+y+z\mid x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}, 0<x<y<z\}=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove $\inf\{x+y+z\mid x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}, 0<x<y<z\}=0$

Let $A=\{x+y+z\mid x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}, 0<x<y<z\}$.

Need to show 3 things:

(1) $\inf A$ exists

(2) 0 is a lower bound for $A$.

(3) 0 is the greatest lower bound of $A$. This is the one I'm having trouble with.

Pf:

(1) If $a\in A$, then $a=x+y+z>0$ for $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R},0<x<y<z$. Since $A$ is nonempty, ordered, and bounded below, then it has the greatest lower bound property and $\inf A$ exists in $\mathbb{R}$.

(2) Let $a\in A$. Then $a=x+y+z$ for some $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$. Since $0<x<y<z$, then

$$0<x<y<z<x+z<2x+z<x+y+z$$

Therefore $a=x+y+z>0$ and 0 is a lower bound of $A$.

(3) Suppose $l$ is any lower bound of $A$ and fix $x\in \mathbb{R},y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $0<x<y$. Then

$$l\le a=x+y+z\space\space\space\space\space\forall z\in\mathbb{R},z>y$$
$$l-x-y\le z$$

So $l-x-y$ is a lower bound of $A$. How can I relate this to 0 as the greatest lower bound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $\ell>0$, let $x=\frac{\ell}8$, $y=\frac{\ell}4$, and $z=\frac{\ell}2$ (or any other distinct fractions of $\ell$ that sum to less than $\ell$).